# Removing spaces from string using pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int n=0;
    char str[100];
    char *ptr,*ptr1;    
    printf("Enter the string = ");
    gets(str);
    ptr = &str[0];
    while(*ptr!='\0')
    {
        n++;ptr++;
    }
    ptr=&str[0];
    while(*ptr!='\0')
    {
        if(*ptr==' ')
        {
            n--;
            for(ptr1=++ptr;*ptr1!='\0';ptr1++)
            {
                *ptr=*ptr1;
                 ptr++;
            }   
            ptr=&str[0];    
        }
        ptr++;
    }
    printf("Modified string = ");
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        printf("%c",str[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know the other way of removing spaces from string but i want to do this using pointers but i cant get what is wrong with this code?

I really appreciate some little help.

Comment: This `ptr=&str[0];` is the same as `ptr = str;`. Also, **DO NOT USE `gets()`**.

Comment: I know that, it just keep things simple

Comment: do not use `gets()`, can buffer overflow.

Comment: `fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin)` looks very simple to me., and `ptr = str;` is certainly simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems

1. In this line

   ```
   for(ptr1 = ++ptr ; *ptr1 != '\0' ; ptr1++)
   ```

   because you increment `ptr` and hence both `ptr1` and `ptr` point to the same place after that, so you are effectively copying the characters to the same place, instead `ptr1` should point to `ptr + 1` while `ptr` should not be modified.
2. You also start at the beggining of the string after "*moving*" all the charaters from the right one place to the left, here

   ```
   ptr = &str[0];
   ```

   right after the loop that moves the characters, you should save the previous position and point to it instead, that would be more efficient.

I've fixed your code and the following code works

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    char  str[100];
    char *ptr;    

    printf("Enter the string = ");
    fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

    ptr = str;
    while (*ptr != '\0')
    {
        char *save;         
        save = ptr;
        if (*ptr == ' ')
        {
            char *next;
            for (next = ptr + 1 ; *next != '\0' ; next++, ptr++)
                *ptr = *next;
            ptr = save;
        }
        ptr++;
    }    
    printf("Modified string = %s\n", str);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yeah u r right about first condtion in for loop.  thanks!

Answer (score 5):

iharob identified your problem and gave a good solution, but I'd like to show you a slightly different approach.

```
char *rd; // "read" pointer
char *wr; // "write" pointer

rd = wr = string; // initially, both read and write pointers point to
                  // beginning of the string

while ( *rd != 0 ) // while not at end of string
{
  while ( isspace( *rd ) ) // while rd points to a whitespace character
    rd++;                  // advance rd
  *wr++ = *rd++;           // copy *rd to *wr, advance both pointers
}
*wr = 0;                   // terminate the result

printf( "squished: %s\n", string );
```

Walking through this with the test string `"This    is a   test"`, we start out as follows (`\0` represents the string terminator):

```
+----------------------- rd
|
V
This    is a   test\0
^
|
+----------------------- wr
```

The first four characters aren't whitespace, so we just overwrite those characters with the same values and advance the two pointers, giving us

```
    +------------------- rd
    |
    V
This    is a   test\0
    ^
    |
    +------------------- wr
```

Since `rd` is pointing to whitespace, we continue to advance it until we find a non-whitespace character:

```
        +--------------- rd
        |
        V
This    is a   test\0
    ^
    |
    +------------------- wr
```

We then write that non-whitespace character to the location pointed to by `wr`:

```
        +--------------- rd
        |
        V
Thisi   is a   test\0
    ^
    |
    +------------------- wr
```

Keep this up until we find the next whitespace character:

```
          +------------- rd
          |
          V
Thisis  is a   test\0
      ^
      |
      +----------------- wr
```

Continue to advance `rd` to the next non-whitespace character:

```
           +------------ rd
           |
           V
Thisis  is a   test\0
      ^
      |
      +----------------- wr
```

Write it to `wr`:

```
           +------------ rd
           |
           V
Thisisa is a   test\0
      ^
      |
      +----------------- wr
```

Lather, rinse, repeat:

```
                   +---- rd
                   |
                   V
Thisisatesta   test\0
           ^
           |
           +------------ wr
```

`rd` now points to the end of the string.  We exit the main loop and write a `0` to `wr` to terminate the string:

```
                   +---- rd
                   |
                   V
Thisisatest\0  test\0
           ^
           |
           +------------ wr
```

I prefer this solution since each character only gets shifted once to its final location.  You wind up overwriting characters that you don't need to at the beginning of the string, but I think that's a reasonable tradeoff.

**Edit**

Chux's version is a bit slicker, and definitely more in the spirit of C:

```
do
{
  while ( isspace( *rd ) )  // while rd points to whitespace
    rd++;                   // advance rd
}
while ( (*wr++ = *rd++) );  // copy rd to wr, advance pointers until
                            // we see the string terminator
```

Again, each character only gets shifted once to its final location.

Comment: Nice - I was hoping to see  an O(n) rather than O(n*n) solution..  Minor: code could use `do { while ( isspace( *rd ) ) rd++;  } while ((*wr++ = *rd++) != '\0');`, yet your code looks easier to understand.

Comment: @chux - yeah, that's definitely slicker and more in the spirit of C than my version.  I could pretend I was writing for clarity, but in truth I just didn't spend too much time thinking about it.

Comment: Your original version will continue past the null terminator if the initial string ends with a space, because `rd` will advance up to the null terminator while skipping spaces in the inner `while` loop, then past it on the following line.